# More than one images in Marquee which should scroll one after another

Tags: html, css

I have created one marquee having one image. I want more than one images in this which should scroll one after another. In my code they comes like one above other and they should be in one div. and i want these images scroll smoothly while in marquee they are scrolling like stopping and scrolling at some time.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a class to your images by floating them to the left:

```
.floatingLeft {
   float: left;
}
```

This should do the job.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7KQML/

Comment: how to connect last element and first element of marquee such that it comes like one after another. there comes little bit gap after when full marquee completes one iteration and starts another iteration.is there any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<MARQUEE behavior="scroll" direction="left" width="100%">
        <img src="yourimagehere1.gif">
        <img src="yourimagehere2.gif">
        <img src="yourimagehere3.gif">
        </MARQUEE>
```

here is a simple example.

Comment: how to connect last element and first element of marquee such that it comes like one after another. there comes little bit gap after when full marquee completes one iteration and starts another iteration.is there any solution for that.